# fixed div with dynamic content not scrolling

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a fixed div with dynamic loaded `li` elements. Now I want the div-content to scroll when there are more than 9 `li` elements and a scroll-bar:

This is what it looks like:

[image]

At the moment the fixed `div` goes on over the footer and the content can not be scrolled.

Here is the css for all `divs`:

```
#fixed-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top:290px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
    min-height: 100%;
}

#absolute-div {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -33px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 33px;
    border-bottom:20px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#map_canvas { /* background */
  clear:left;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index:-1001;
 /* height: 530px;*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<body>

                <div id="searchbox">  

                <div id="absolute-div" class="clear-block">


                        <form method="post" action="./index.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="clinic-finder-form" class="clear-block" class="clear-block">


                             <label for="edit-gmap-address">Standort angeben und Vorteile in der Umgebung finden: </label>
                             <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="address" id="address" size="60" value="" class="form-text" autocomplete="off" />
                <?php 
                            // support unicode
                            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
                            $cats = $db->get_rows("SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.id!='' ORDER BY categories.cat_name ASC");

                            ?>


                             <select name="products" class="form-select" id="edit-products" ><option value="">Alle Kategorien</option>
                             <?php if(!empty($cats)): ?>
                                <?php foreach($cats as $k=>$v): ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $v['id']; ?>"><?php echo $v['cat_name']; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                             </select>


                            <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Vorteile finden" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-0168068fce35cf80f346d6c1dbd7344e" value="form-0168068fce35cf80f346d6c1dbd7344e"  />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-clinic-finder-form" value="clinic_finder_form"  />

                            <input type="button" name="op" onclick="document.location.href='newstore.php'" id="edit-submit" value="Unternehmen vorschlagen" class="btn btn-primary" />


                            </form>

</div></div>
        <div id="fixed-div">
                      <div id="clinic-finder" class="clear-block">
                      <div id="results">        


                        <ol style="display: block; " id="list"></ol>
                      </div>
                      </div>

        </div>

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="footer">&copy; 2008-2013 Ihr Vorteilsclub - Impressum</div>
```

Thanks a lot! Marcel

Comment: add overflow:scroll to your fixed div. and give specific height to that div.

Comment: Please include some HTML: is fixed-div within absolute-div? You can probably fix it with `overflow:auto` on fixed-div, but it is hard to tell without some markup

Comment: add ovrflow:scroll  in your div

Comment: in simple word you can achieve your desired results through (overflow:scroll;) but if u need more so please make live demo of your complete HTML and CSS for us  that would be much better for us to help out of u

Comment: overflow:scroll works but only with specific height. Is there any way to do this with height:100%?

Comment: it depend on your content  and according to that it get overflow

Comment: why dont you set the container height to `height: 100vh` to fill the viewport and then use `overflow-y: scroll`, you would need to use some javascript to force the height on older browser versions if `height: 100%` doesn't work

Answer (score 18):

Add this to your css:

```
#results {        
    height: 100%; 
    overflow-y: scroll; /* adds scrollbar */
}
```

Comment: thanks this works but also only with specific height. Is there any way to do this with full height to the footer?

Comment: I've just edited, not sure if comment was before or after edit. This version applies only to results div so as not to affect outer div

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with absolute positioning.  You still need `overflow-y: scroll`.  Absolutely position the top of the dynamic section to the total height of the fixed elements above it  and the bottom to the total height of the fixed elements below it.  May need to tweak slightly but that should do the trick of consuming all the intermediate space and scrolling the overflow.